# React useEffect Infinite Loop even though dependency list is provided

Tags: reactjs

I just started studying React Hooks so I'm kind of a newbie here.

I'm struggling to find out why the below code falls into an infinite loop.

I can't find any problems with a code.

Is there anyone who could sort out this problem?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export interface Post {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

function PostFetchingOne() {
  const [id, setId] = useState(1);
  const [post, setPost] = useState<Partial<Post>>({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setPost(res.data);
        console.log("post => ", post);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [id, post]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setId(+e.target.value)}
          value={id}
        />
      </div>
      <div>{post.title}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default PostFetchingOne;
```

Comment: Please remove the dependencies from useEffect.

Comment: Thanks, Krushnasinh for the feedback. removing dependencies will definitely stop an infinite loop but it also prevents state from working properly.

Comment: You should only remove `post` from dependencies. `id` is a correct dependency, `post` is not. If you want to `console.log` your `post` state that should be in a dedicated `useEffect` and that will certainly have `post` as a dependency: `useEffect(() => { console.log('post => ', post); }, [post]);`

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks for accurate the answer Ibsn!

Answer (score 1):

The second param of useEffect is an array of dependencies - when they change, useEffect will fire again.
Inside your useEffect action, you perform an update to "post" on your axios get's callback.

Hence, until the axios get will fail, you'll have an infinite loop.

The solution here probably will be to remove "post" from the useEffect's dependency array.

Comment: Great! Thanks, Ben for an accurate answer. It is working perfectly.